# "<" and ">" is not showing in SMS

Tags: php, urlencode, sms-gateway

I am trying to send an SMS by PHP - Laravel. The SMS is sending very nicely but it is removing `<` and `>` sign from the message. Here is my code

**Controller**

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $number = $request->get('number');
    $otp = rand(1000,9999);
    $client = Client::query()->where('number',$number)->exists();

    if($client){
        $message = "<#> Your otp verification code is ".$otp."\nLet's get started your journey with BodLai!!!\nPlease don't share this code with others fdjweisjdfl";
    }else{
        Client::query()->create($request->all());
        $message = "<#> Your otp verification code is ".$otp."\nLet's get started your journey with BodLai!!!\nPlease don't share this code with others fdjweisjdfl";
    }

    $this->verificationSMS($number,$message);

    return ['otp_pin'=>$otp];
}

public function verificationSMS($number,$message)
{
    $api_key = "[api_key]";
    $senderid = [sender_id];
    $URL = "http://esms.mimsms.com/smsapi?api_key=".$api_key."&type=text&contacts=".$number."&senderid=".$senderid."&msg=".urlencode($message);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);

}
```

These codes are working fine. But I am receiving SMS without `<` and `>`.

Example:

> # Your otp verification code is 1984
>   Let's get started your journey with BodLai!!!
>   Please don't share this code with others fdjweisjdfl

My question is, How can I send `<` and `>` sign in the SMS? I've tried UNICODE and HEX CODE instead of these sign, none of them worked.

Comment: This seems like a question better suited for esms.mimsms.com's technical support.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks. I will do that too.